# Webkit seems to have issue with percentage widths/heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit, cross-browser

I am trying to set up some sliding transitions between questions on a site. It all works perfectly in Firefox, but exhibits strange behaviour in Webkit

[The Site](http://mildfuzz.com/jQuestions/)

I have boiled it down to the fact that if I replace the percentages in `css({'bottom':'-100%'})` or `css({'left':'-100%'})` with actual values, the problem goes away. But this isn't ideal, so I wondered if there was a browser bug anyone was aware of, with a fix.

Long shot, but you don't ask you don't get!

Comment: Try using `$(window).height()*-1` and `$(window).width()*-1`

Comment: yeah, I got that. In terms of the class, it's not practical to implement that (if there is a better way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascript library ( since I don't think it's your code ) **is holding it wrong.**

instead of going 100% 99% .. 1% 0

It's doing 100% 99px .. 1px 0,

Maybe adding proper parent's with fixed dimensions and relative positions will help, but it's a bug in that library anyway. It's never a good idea to stack percents with no fixed dimensions anywhere.

Comment: great answer, can I ask how you established it?

Comment: I paused the script execution to check for the current inline styles.